# Is there some sort of constructor being generated here?

Tags: sorting, go

In one of the sorting examples, they use the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %d", p.Name, p.Age)
}

// ByAge implements sort.Interface for []Person based on
// the Age field.
type ByAge []Person

func (a ByAge) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByAge) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByAge) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Age < a[j].Age }

func main() {
    people := []Person{
        {"Bob", 31},
        {"John", 42},
        {"Michael", 17},
        {"Jenny", 26},
    }

    fmt.Println(people)
    sort.Sort(ByAge(people))
    fmt.Println(people)

}
```

The line with the Sort is a bit confusing for me:

```
sort.Sort(ByAge(people))
```

Does ByAge(people) generate some kind of constructor that copies the array being passed in? I'm not sure I understand how the new type, ByAge, has access to the elements otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `foo(expr)` where `foo` is a type and `expr` is a *type conversion,* as described in the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> ### Conversions
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x`
>   is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.
>
> ```
> Conversion = Type "(" Expression [ "," ] ")" .
> ```
>
> If the type starts with
>   the operator `*` or `<-`, or if the type starts with the keyword `func` and
>   has no result list, it must be parenthesized when necessary to avoid
>   ambiguity:
>
> ```
> *Point(p)        // same as *(Point(p))
> (*Point)(p)      // p is converted to *Point
> <-chan int(c)    // same as <-(chan int(c))
> (<-chan int)(c)  // c is converted to <-chan int
> func()(x)        // function signature func() x
> (func())(x)      // x is converted to func()
> (func() int)(x)  // x is converted to func() int
> func() int(x)    // x is converted to func() int (unambiguous)
> ```
>
> A constant value `x` can
>   be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - `x` is representable by a value of type `T`.
> - `x` is a floating-point constant, `T` is a floating-point type, and `x` is representable by a value of type `T` after rounding using IEEE 754 round-to-even rules. The constant `T(x)` is the rounded value.
> - `x` is an integer constant and `T` is a string type. The same rule as for non-constant `x` applies in this case.
>
> Converting a constant yields a typed constant as result.
>
> ```
> uint(iota)               // iota value of type uint
> float32(2.718281828)     // 2.718281828 of type float32
> complex128(1)            // 1.0 + 0.0i of type complex128
> float32(0.49999999)      // 0.5 of type float32
> string('x')              // "x" of type string
> string(0x266c)           // "♬" of type string
> MyString("foo" + "bar")  // "foobar" of type MyString
> string([]byte{'a'})      // not a constant: []byte{'a'} is not a constant
> (*int)(nil)              // not a constant: nil is not a constant, *int is not a boolean, numeric, or string type
> int(1.2)                 // illegal: 1.2 cannot be represented as an int
> string(65.0)             // illegal: 65.0 is not an integer constant
> ```
>
> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T
>   in any of these cases:
>
> - `x` is assignable to `T`.
> - `x`'s type and `T`have identical underlying types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are unnamed pointer types and their pointer base types
>     have identical underlying types.
> - `x`'s type and `T` are both integer or floating point types. `x`'s type and `T` are both complex types.
> - `x` is an integer or a slice of bytes or runes and `T` is a string type.
> - `x` is a string and `T` is a slice of bytes or runes.
>
> Specific rules apply to
>   (non-constant) conversions between numeric types or to and from a
>   string type. These conversions may change the representation of `x` and
>   incur a run-time cost. All other conversions only change the type but
>   not the representation of `x`.
>
> There is no linguistic mechanism to convert between pointers and
>   integers. The package unsafe implements this functionality under
>   restricted circumstances.

See the linked page for more details.